# three.js in React - THREE.ShaderTerrain missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, renderer

I need to make a 3D map from heightmap image in React and I came across [this website](http://www.smartjava.org/content/threejs-render-real-world-terrain-heightmap-using-open-data/) which has a decent demo I wanted to implement in my application as a beginning.

The very problem of this example is that the ShaderTerrain property is completely missing (at least in my application). Am I missing an import? Here is the error I am getting:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'ShaderTerrain' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you have linked is many years old. The respective demo uses `three.js` in version `r49`. The current release is `r115`. In the past, `ShaderTerrain` was first renamed to `TerrainShader` and later removed with release `r112`.

However, you can move back in time with this [URL](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/75dc017ad934b1f65ac376634b68ccb5d8f042a6/examples/js/ShaderTerrain.js) and copy the code to your project.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Would you please suggest a working contemporary demo for the same purpose (if there is one)?

Comment: Sorry, there is no such demo in the official repository.